# Declaring more than one handler in the same struct sigaction?

Tags: c, struct, signals

I don't understand why and how this can be possible, in set_handler before the loop start `i set 2handlers in the same struct sigaction and works`. This doesn't make sense to me, like i think that the correct way to use this is say **sa->handler = h_int** and then in another struct sigaction say: **sb->sa_handler = h_quit**. But using the same struct works too and i don't know how, i tried put in debugger and couldn't see nothing that makes senses, i tried declare this two handlers in main() and don't use set_handler but did not work so this get more confuse. And there is some way to do this without use this function set_handler? like do this in the main

```c
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void set_handler(int sig, void (*handler)(int), struct sigaction *sa);
static void h_int(int sig);
static void h_quit(int sig);

int main(void)
{
    struct sigaction sa;

    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    set_handler(SIGINT, h_int, &sa);
    set_handler(SIGQUIT, h_quit, &sa);
    /* set_handler(SIGQUIT, SIG_IGN, &sa); */
    while(1)
    {
    }
}

static void set_handler(int sig, void (*handler)(int), struct sigaction *sa)
{
    sa->sa_handler = handler;
    sigaction(sig, sa, NULL);
}

static void h_int(int sig)
{
    (void)sig;
    printf("hi C+c\n");
}

static void h_quit(int sig)
{
    (void)sig;
    printf("ok C+\\");
}
```

Comment: BTW: you should not call printf(and friends) from a signal handler/

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem.  The kernel makes a copy of the relevant information from the structure when you call `sigaction()`.  It does not rely on the structure you pass continuing to be valid after it returns control to your code.

Answer (score 0):

The copy of a `struct sigaction` whose address is passed to the `sigaction` function is not saved in any way.  Once `sigaction` returns that copy of the struct may freely be used for something else.

If this wasn't the case, then you wouldn't be able to use a function like this:

```
void setup_signal()
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.sa_handler = h_int;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);
}
```

Since `sa` goes out of scope once the function returns.  But because the contents of `sa` is only used to set up the signal handler, there is no problem.